# How to read online html document to string in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, parsing, cors

I am trying to read online html document and parse some data from it using Angular. The problem is I am keep getting an error about `cors`. My code for reading html document is:

```
  loadParsingData(htmlToParse:String){
     let retVal = this.http.get(htmlToParse.toString())
     .map(res => res.text())
     return retVal; }
```

When I try to test this code I expect to get html document from given website (for example imdb most popular movies) as argument, but all I get is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.imdb.com/chart/moviemeter?ref_=nv_mv_mpm_8. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Can anyone please help me? Thank you in beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send your request through a CORS proxy instead.

Where you’re specifying the URL `http://www.imdb.com/chart/moviemeter?ref_=nv_mv_mpm_8` in your code now, just replace that with this URL:

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.imdb.com/chart/moviemeter?ref_=nv_mv_mpm_8
```

That will cause the request to be sent to `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`, a proxy that will then send the request on to `http://www.imdb.com/chart/moviemeter?ref_=nv_mv_mpm_8`. And when that proxy gets the response, it will take it and add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to it and then pass that back to your requesting frontend code as the response.

That response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what your browser sees, so the error message the browser is showing you now goes away, and the browser allows your frontend JavaScript code to access the response.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS has general details on CORS, and  ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/42744707#42744707) is an answer with more details about how you can set up your own CORS proxy.